# C++ for loop crashes halfway through

Tags: c++, for-loop

I've just started learning about C++ and I'm currently stuck with this for loop that crashes everytime I execute it (it's part of a larger code)

```
void placeItem()
{
    int settler = 20, castle = 5, tower = 10, mine = 10, E = 100;
    int player1Settler = 0, player1Castle = 0, player1Tower = 0, player1Mine = 0;
    int player2Settler = 0, player2Castle = 0, player2Tower = 0, player2Mine = 0;
    int dice, x, y;
    currentBoardStatus();
    cout << "Player " << playerTurn(1 || 2) << " starts first." << endl;
    for (int game = 1; game <= 46; game++)
    {
        system("CLS");
        cout << "Turn #" << game << endl;
        dice = rand() % 6 + 1;
        x = rand() % 10 + 1;
        y = rand() % 10 + 1;
        cout << "Dice number: " << dice << endl;
        if (dice < 4 && settler > 0)
        {
            cout << "Settler placed on [" << x << "] [" << y << "]" << endl;
            gameBoard(x, y) = "S";
            settler = settler--;
            if (playerTurn(1))
            {
                player1Settler = player1Settler + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                player2Settler = player2Settler + 1;
            }
            currentBoardStatus();
        }
        else if (dice = 4 && castle > 0)
        {
            cout << "Castle placed on [" << x << "] [" << y << "]" << endl;
            gameBoard(x, y) = "C";
            castle = castle--;
            if (playerTurn(1))
            {
                player1Castle = player1Castle + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                player2Castle = player2Castle + 1;
            }
            currentBoardStatus();
        }
        else if (dice = 5 && tower > 0)
        {
            cout << "Tower placed on [" << x << "] [" << y << "]" << endl;
            gameBoard(x, y) = "T";
            tower = tower--;
            if (playerTurn(1))
            {
                player1Tower = player1Tower + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                player2Tower = player2Tower + 1;
            }
            currentBoardStatus();
        }
        else if (dice = 6 && mine > 0)
        {
            cout << "Mine placed on [" << x << "] [" << y << "]" << endl;
            gameBoard(x, y) = "M";
            mine = mine--;
            if (playerTurn(1))
            {
                player1Mine = player1Mine + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                player2Mine = player2Mine + 1;
            }
            currentBoardStatus();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Player skips his/her turn." << endl;
        }
        nextTurn();
        //currentBoardStatus();
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

As soon as the loop goes to 16, the entire console application stops responding, and stops there, only letting me exit.

Comment: Place a breakpoint at the for loop, press F5 15 times, then press the next statement button and go line by line until it exits. You should find the problem.

Comment: `gameBoard(x, y)` does that return a reference to `std::string` ?

Comment: If you post a drop box link to the entire code I'll debug it.

Comment: Note: the if(dice = 4 ... and if(dice = 6 ... ASSIGN dice the value 4 and 6, respectively. You want if(dice == 4 ...  etc. A standard coding technique is to ALWAYS put the constant first in equal comparisons. if(4 == dice...  , because if(4 = dice is illegal and will give a compiler error.   Also, x and y seem to be in the range of 1 to N. Is this the range expected by gameboard(x,y)?  Also, have you called srand(...) somewhere else to randomize rand()?

Comment: what is in the gameBoard definition btw may be problem lies there?

Comment: @NicholasPipitone https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9131401/code.txt

Comment: @Ventus I tried to run it and it went all the way to round 47, not 16. You should try to debug it and see where it eventually crashes. ( I'm compiling this on my phone, so I set rand() to return 123456789 and took out sleep n system, may have something to do with it )

Comment: you may want to compare like `(dice == 4)` or `(dice == 5)` because when you do `(dice = 4)` you actually assign `dice` the value `4` and the `if` will evaluate `(dice = 4 && castle > 0)` as only `(castle > 0)`

Comment: I would suggest doing `if( system("CLR") ) system("clear");`, some OSs with have it called `clear` instead of `CLR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code crashes because of

```
string gameBoard(int i, int j)
{
    string arr[10][10];
    return arr[i][j];
}
```

AND

```
x = rand() % 10 + 1;
y = rand() % 10 + 1;
```

`x` and `y` will have a value between 1 and 10, but the size of arr is 10 and its maximum valid index is 9. Therefore if `x` or `y` is 10 (or both), they'll access undefined memory.

Aside from this, there are many flaws with your code like:

1. `dice = 4` when wanting to compare the value (which actually assigns the value 4 to `dice` as @KeithSmith pointed out)
2. The fact that you create `string arr` in `int main()` and never use it, but declare another `string arr` inside `string gameBoard()` and then return an index from it (which is undefined)

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe I've overlooked that!

Comment: What is the function gameBoard meant to do anyway? :/ Every time it runs, it's declaring a 2D array of strings, and returns an element from that array?

Comment: You should make `string arr` a global and use it inside `gameBoard()`. Also, some validations before getting the indexes wouldn't be a bad idea :)

Comment: `string arr[10][10]; //global`
and `string& gameBoard(int i, int j){return arr[i][j];}`